# Pass a function with parameters specified for resample() method on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, function, datetime, pandas

I want to pass a function to resample() on a pandas dataframe with certain parameters specified when it is passed (as opposed to defining several separate functions).

This is the function

```
import itertools
def spell(X, kind='wet', how='mean', threshold=0.5): 

    if kind=='wet':
        condition = X>threshold
    else:
        condition = X<=threshold

    length = [sum(1 if x==True else nan for x in group) for key,group in itertools.groupby(condition)]

    if not length: 
        res = 0
    elif how=='mean': 
        res = np.mean(length)
    else:
        res = np.max(length)

    return res
```

here is a dataframe

```
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='1960-01-01', periods=100, freq='d')
values = np.random.random(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(values, index=idx)
```

And heres sort of what I want to do with it

```
df.resample('M', how=spell(kind='dry',how='max',threshold=0.7))
```

But I get the error `TypeError: spell() takes at least 1 argument (3 given)`. I want to be able to pass this function with these parameters specified except for the input array. Is there a way to do this?

EDIT:

X is the input array that is passed to the function when calling the resample method on a dataframe object like so `df.resample('M', how=my_func)` for a monthly resampling interval.

If I try `df.resample('M', how=spell)` I get:

```
0
1960-01-31  1.875000
1960-02-29  1.500000
1960-03-31  1.888889
1960-04-30  3.000000
```

which is exactly what I want for the default parameters but I want to be able to specify the input parameters to the function before passing it. This might include storing the definition in another variable but I'm not sure how to do this with the default parameters changed.

Comment: Your question is kind of missing a few things that would help. What is X- are you trying to pass a dataframe to this function? The pandas resample function expects a specific string to be passed to the how parameter. Like 'mean' or 'max'. You're function appears to only be returning a value- res?

Comment: I've edited the question. Basically when calling resample() on a dataframe a numpy array is passed for the resampling interval chosen which is monthly here so X would be a numpy array. Function can be passed to the how parameter as I've shown above but I need a way to change the default parameters before passing without having to redefine or define new functions with different default parameters

Comment: typically the functions passed to the 'how' argument do return a single value, which is what I'm doing here. I haven't tried it yet but I think the resample method can return python objects too.

Answer (score -1):

I think this may be what you're looking for, though it's a little hard to tell.. Let me know if this helps. First, the example dataframe:

```
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='1960-01-01', periods=100, freq='d')
values = np.random.random(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(values, index=idx)
```

EDIT- had a greater than instead of less than or equal to originally...
Next, the function:

```
def spell(df, column='', kind='wet', rule='M', how='mean', threshold=0.5): 
    if kind=='wet':
        df = df[df[column] > threshold]
    else:
        df = df[df[column] <= threshold]

    df = df.resample(rule=rule, how=how)
    return df
```

So, you would call it by:

```
spell(df, 0)
```

To get:

```
               0
1960-01-31  0.721519
1960-02-29  0.754054
1960-03-31  0.746341
1960-04-30  0.654872
```

You can change around the parameters as well:

```
spell(df, 0, kind='something else', rule='W', how='max', threshold=0.7)


            0
1960-01-03  0.570638
1960-01-10  0.529357
1960-01-17  0.565959
1960-01-24  0.682973
1960-01-31  0.676349
1960-02-07  0.379397
1960-02-14  0.680303
1960-02-21  0.654014
1960-02-28  0.546587
1960-03-06  0.699459
1960-03-13  0.626460
1960-03-20  0.611464
1960-03-27  0.685950
1960-04-03  0.688385
1960-04-10  0.697602
```

Comment: Interesting approach, however this doesn't actually do what the function is doing. The function is counting the occurences of values above a threshold that are in a sequence and takes the average for the array that is passed to it which corresponds to each month. I'm trying to think of how to modify this but I keep coming back to having to pass the function to resample (besides essentially rewriting the resample function)

Comment: Try adjusting the how parameter. You can pass multiple functions. For example, instead of just mean maybe ['mean', 'count'] ?

Comment: count won't do it because `length = [sum(1 for x in group) for key,group in itertools.groupby(condition) if key]` is finding all the sequences of numbers within the threshold condition and counting their individual lengths in days. It seems like the only alternative is to create separate functions for each set of arguments

Comment: Are you trying to look at both the groups above and below the threshold? The current function eliminates those above/below the threshold based on the kind

Comment: Either above or below based on kind argument but it needs to count the number in a sequence ie. adjacent to one another as opposed to all the numbers fitting one condition. I update the question because the line I mentioned should actually be this `length = [sum(1 if x==True else nan for x in group) for key,group in itertools.groupby(condition)]`